# If I didn't activate my find my iPhone is it possible for the thief to reset factory settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, find-my-iphone

I just got my iPhone stolen. I quickly turn on find my iPhone. I wonder if before I did that the thief have reset factory setting first. Is it possible?

It seems that the mere act of setting my iPhone on password should make the iPhone unusable even without find my iPhone feature. Am I correct here?

Comment: Is it currently stolen or did you get it back after it was stolen? I can't get how you turned FindMyiPhone on afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't enabled Find My iPhone, then you haven't enabled Activation Lock, which means the device can be reset simply by placing it in Recovery Mode and clicking Restore in iTunes. Setting a passcode protects the information on the device but won't prevent against restoring the OS.

Comment: What about if I turned on find my iPhone but the thief restore the factory setting before I enter lost mode?

Comment: @Jim Activation Lock would prevent the device from being activated regardless of whether lost mode is on. Restoring a device with Find My iPhone active is not possible using the normal method—the device must enter Recovery/DFU mode first to bypass iTunes restrictions, but then Activation Lock would be activated and the device unable to be activated and still be able to be tracked with Find My iPhone.

Comment: What is activation lock? I have activated find my iPhone. Did I activate activation lock?

Comment: @Jim Activation Lock is a feature of Find My iPhone that prevents devices being activated after being restored. Enabling Find My iPhone allows Activation Lock to be activated should the device be restored.